Pagination links hidden by styles
Pagination links are hidden by styles as you can see on the screenshot. Does this affect the Google bot that should scan and index them? In theory, it shouldn't care about styles, the main thing is the markup?


In 2021, Google's John Mueller said it was fine, but not best practise - https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-on-using-css-to-hide-links/422162/ - Hidden internal links aren't really spam in the way hidden external links are, so that would make sense to still be the case.
